# Why doesn't my CSS Scroll Snap Points work with `div`'s?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm trying to make my CSS Scroll Snap Points work.  I have a main container (`div`), called `website`, and inside that I have four images , set to scroll horizontally with CSS.  I want the four images to have text as well as images (and other stuff).  Therefore I need to use `div`s to contain those elements.

When I use just the four images (`img`), the horizontal scroll works.  However, if I add the `div`s around my images, the horizontal scroll doesn't work anymore, and it ends up looking like I put the images vertically on top of each other (normal format).

Why doesn't the horizontal scroll work with the `div`'s, and how can I fix it?

---

Here's the code without the `div`s (horizontal scroll works):

```css
#website {
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 -webkit-white-space: nowrap;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 0;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
 -webkit-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
 scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
 scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
}

img {
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>


<body>
<div id="website">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/1.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/2.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/3.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/4.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</body>
```

And here's the code with the `div`s (horizontal scroll doesn't work):

```css
#website {
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 -webkit-white-space: nowrap;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 0;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
 -webkit-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
 scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
 scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
}

.page {
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link href="http://www.jeffarries.com/tests/scroll.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<body>
<div id="website">
 <div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/1.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/2.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/3.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/4.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `CSS` a little bit.
This should work:

```
.page {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: WOW!! That did it!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: There only is one issue, if I add some text, i.e. a `p` element, that screws it up as well.  As you can see on my website, I added a `p` element and now it doesn't work again, do you know why that is? The page is here: http://www.jeffarries.com/tests/test

Comment: To add text on top of the image, place `<p>` before the image and use `{ position: relative;
top: 125px;
color: #000;
font-size: 18px; }`